# Can hydraulic clutch line be easily replaced with a cable?

Tags: honda, civic, clutch

I've got a 92 Civic (first year with a hydraulic clutch instead of a simple cable) with a slight clutch fluid leak somewhere, and I'm curious if, when it gets bad enough to need fixing, it might be feasible to just replace it with a straight cable. My old (88) Civic had a cable instead of hydraulics for the clutch and the feel/response of the clutch pedal was a lot better. Aside from that, it just seems a lot simpler/cheaper to maintain and a lot better environmentally.

Anyway, is this replacement feasible? What would it involve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is feasible but it would be more expensive than repairing your current setup. It would involve swapping the pedal assembly, the clutch fork, finding all the brackets for routing the cable and possibly the transmission.

The upside of cables is they are cheap to replace. The downside is they need to be adjusted as they stretch and they tend to fail with no warning.

The upside of hydraulic clutches are they self adjust, they tend to last a long time, they take up less space in the engine compartment, and when they do fail they tend to fail slowly, usually due to a leak. Generally the leak is at the slave cylinder, which is replaceable.